# Regex for everything except the last two characters?

Tags: regex

Can someone help me with the regex for every character except the last two?

For example:
`us-central1-1` should return `us-central1`
`europe-west4-a` should return `europe-west4`

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Is the pattern *always* characters dash characters dash one character?

Comment: `/^(.*).{2}$/` should work

Comment: (\w+-\w+)- should do the job.

Comment: Please include how far you've got (show your current pattern) and would be nice if you added some context to the question :)

Answer (score 1):

```
^(.*)..$
```

This should work where:

- ^ start of string
- $ end of string
- .. last 2 chars
- (.*) the matching group that you want

**note:** . (dot) matches any charachers except line terminators